# Trying to use Bootstrap via Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use Bootstrap in my website by referring to it's examples, except, for some reason, the dropdown examples it provides don't work; it just displays a blank page. What I did, in order to make sure I wasn't missing anything, was I went to the Bootstrap website, went to customise, and ensured that I downloaded all possible CSS/Javascript files, ensuring that all possible functions/features were included.

Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to do.

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../assets/bs/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../assets/bs/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>

  <div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn dropdown-toggle sr-only" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
   </button>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src=".../assets/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Bootstrap Javascript -->
  <script src=".../assets/bs/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

The page is connecting to the scripts, I confirmed this through Google Chrome's inspector. What is more confusing is that I am able to implement SOME of Bootstrap's features, but not all, for example I can create buttons with icons it provides, but I can't create dropdowns.

I've researched this issue, but none of the solutions it provides resolves it. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Please reply soon, many thanks.

---

After several checks, I should clarify that yes, I'm using the most up to date Bootstrap, that I should of mentioned that I'm displaying the page through CodeIgniter, and at the moment I am still having difficulty getting it to work, but I will be working on it until I do.

Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Bootstrap tutorials are not fully compatible with the Bootstrap files, in this case, the drop-downs. Specifically the CSS files provided cannot display drop-downs through the examples that the website has provided, so either the tutorial requires updating or the CSS files do.

Currently, v2.3.2 can display drop-downs through the examples given, which could be accessed like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css">
```

Also by referring to other examples, I was able to get this feature to work to an extent, even while using v3.1.0.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Tutorials<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">MySQL</a></li>
        <li class="divider"></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HTML5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So in short, either the CSS files requires updating, or the tutorials do.

Many thanks to those who replied and assisted me in allocating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried recreating your code using Bootply,

this is with Bootstrap 2.3.1 and jQuery 2.0.2

It seems to work fine. It might be because of the version of jQuery you are using

[Demo here](http://bootply.com/111457)

---

**EDIT**

I have noticed that in your code, you did not indicate the doctype.

This one is stated on the Bootstrap docs:

> **HTML5 doctype**
>
> Bootstrap makes use of certain HTML elements and CSS
>   properties that require the use of the HTML5 doctype. Include it at
>   the beginning of all your projects.
>
> source : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  ...
</html>
```

Comment: Yeah you're using Bootstrap 2.3.1 like Paul had mentioned, it could be that the Bootstrap I'm using is out of date.

Comment: Then you can try downloading the latest version [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.1.0/bootstrap-3.1.0-dist.zip)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm using the version you gave me but I can't get it to work still. By the way I'm using jQuery v2.1.0 and this is Bootstrap v3.1.0.

Comment: Well that is strange, have you tried using a lower version of jQuery?

Comment: Thanks for your replies, and I've included the doctype within my coding, but I still can't get it to work. I've also researched further into Bootstrap v3.1.0 and apparently in was released on January the 30th of this year so it's a very recent update. Is it possible that the current tutorials that Bootstrap provides have not been updated yet?

Comment: First stop would to check with the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template).

Then maybe check [here](http://bootswatch.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You could be using an older version of Bootstrap.

If I remember correctly, you need to add the "dropdown" javascript file separately in the old versions.

I would upgrade to 2.3.1, failing that find the dropdown javascript file and add that too.

2.3.1 docs can be found here:

http://bootstrapdocs.com/v2.3.1/docs/

Otherwise, what errors do you see in the Firebug / Chrome Console window?

Comment: I got the Bootstrap files from this: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/. If this is the old version, where would I get the new version? Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: I'll check it now and see if it helps. Again, thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: Any reason why your scripts aren't in the head section?

Comment: It was how I was taught. To be honest, before I did this, I was trying to find a template example of how every HTML page should be structured , like rules, standards, what every page should include and where. You wouldn't happen to do a good template example I to follow?

Comment: In terms of the Chrome Console question, nothing pops up. No warnings, no dangers, nothing.

Comment: Also I just looked up the Bootstrap version number and it says v3.1.0 so I'm assuming that it's the most up to date Bootstrap.

Comment: That could be your problem.  Bootstrap 3 is quite different.  Follow these docs for your dropdown: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns.  Also get the latest version of jQuery

Comment: Thanks for your replies, and yes, I'm using the latest version of jQuery, v2.1.0. I've also researched further into Bootstrap v3.1.0 and apparently in was released on January the 30th of this year so it's a very recent update. Is it possible that the current tutorials that Bootstrap provides have not been updated yet?